# How to get Watch OS crash logs into App Store Connect?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

We are developing a Watch OS companion application for our iOS app. We currently get symbolicated crash reports for our iOS app on App Store Connect. We are trying to get the same for the Watch Application.

We are producing some forced crashes on a build we uploaded to TestFlight but crash logs are not getting there as iOS crash logs. Is there anything else that needs to be done differently from iOS to get them?

Do you know about any known issues on it?

BTW, we see the crash logs getting to the iPhone on the iPhone itself. They're just not uploaded. We are also able to get the logs on Xcode Organizer.